# Hibernate : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: hibernate

I am getting **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException** exception while trying to run the main method which has the `SessionFactory` and `AnnotationConfiguration` details.

The exception displayed is

```
"Caused by:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatetutorials.student_information' doesn't exist"
```

where **hibernatetutorials** is the name of the database.

I have already tried to change **hibernate.hbm2dll.auto** property in **hibernate.cfg.xml** file to create-drop and create. Further i also tried to run the code with different versions of hibernate (4.3 and 3.6.10)
However nothing seems to be working . ........

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <!-- Connecting to database -->
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateTutorials</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">******</property>

    <!-- disable auto commit -->
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool size-->
    <property name = "connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Verbose Mode : print SQL query to console -->
    <property name = "show_sql">true</property>
    <property name = "format_sql">true</property>
    <property name = "use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <!--  -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>

    <!-- for jdbc transactions -->
    <property name = "hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <!-- mapping file  -->
    <mapping class="com.sanchit.hibernate.Student_Info" />
</session-factory>
```

Comment: It says your student_information table does not exist.

Comment: hibernate is supposed to create the table itself if  "hibernate.hbm2dll.auto" property is set to "create" in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Can you post hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: Hey Darshan, I created a table "STUDENT_INFORMATION" in hibernateTutorials and ran the code again....it is working., but i have read in many places that ***hibernate.hbm2dll.auto*** when set to "create" should automatically create the table. 

Also in my POJO class  "Student_Info.java" i have a a field called "rollNo" (Primary Key) and i am passing value 24 to it....but the compiler is somehow automatically taking the value 0 for that field. ...

Comment: Yes, when **hibernate.hbm2dll.auto** set to create it creates a new table deleting the old data. And for primary key "rollNo" you need to tell hibernate that you will explicitly assign values to it simply leaving "<generator />" for Ids in **hibernate.cfg.xml** should do the trick.

Comment: but i am not using GenerationType.AUTO in my ID field....so it should not generate values automatically.....
also can you pls elaborate how to use <generator/> for Ids ?

Comment: That's the dig. Do not use any @GeneratedValue for the ID if you are using annotations.

Comment: as i am using MySQL5  **hence <property name = hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>** ..the dialect should be MySQL5....
but now i have another question....why is it automatically generating value 0 for Id field..it should set the value whatever i am passing as parameter......as i am not using any GenerationType for ID

Comment: Ok please post your mapping file for the class if you are using it, or your pojo if you are using annotation for hibernate mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see here it's a bad typing in the hibernate properties. This line

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</property>`

must be

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

In this way the table will be created.

If you want the old table be deleted and created again:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Remember to add `5` between `MySQL` and `Dialect`.